# Prototype experience: Unity3D vs UDK

Tags: unity, udk

Has anyone yet prototyped a game in **both** Unity3D and UDK?

If so, which features made prototyping the game easier or more difficult in each toolkit?

Was one prototype demonstrably better than the other (given the same starting assets)?

I'm looking for specific answers with regard to using the toolkit features, not a comparison of available features. E.g. Destructable terrain is easier in toolkit X for reasons Y and Z.

I can code, so the limitations of the inbuilt scripting languages are not a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I set up a simple platformer prototype for iOS with both UDK and Unity from having zero experience with either.

The tools for Unity are a lot more intuitive all around, and because of this I was a lot more productive.

The existing classes for use in Unity and the overall component-based structure is a lot more consistent than UDKs, where it's very difficult to know the exact responsibilities each object has and which objects it communicates with, without doing research or digging through the code.

The fact that I could make changes even while the Unity game was running was nice.

UDK did have a iOS controller, where you could send inputs to your Windows PC from your iPhone or iPad - Unity did have this but it was mac only.

I didn't use the same assets for both prototypes (I used assets that came with the development kits), but neither prototype was demonstrably better than the other, they were virtually identical.

Comment: I would agree with this. The UDK isn't very intuitive and not incrdibly well documented; expect reading through lots of code to find what you want. Unity is very fast for prototyping; we prototyped 4 or 5 different playable gameplays in 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Udk is based on a shooter for that engine to prototype that type of game is better.

But Unity is very intuitive and easy to work with and also has a store with a lot of tools at low price for various tasks.
A very useful tools within Unity for prototyping are [Action Box](http://www.athagon.com/actionbox/) and [Prototype](http://www.protoolsforunity3d.com/prototype/). It is also essential to use the snap (sortcut: Ctrl) and snap polygon (sortcut: v) to place the blocks precisely

Good luck!